# TypeError: posts.map is not a function, trying to populate fields from a REST api

Tags: reactjs, rest, use-effect

I am trying to implement something like a Photosharing application in React JS Like Facebook, etc.
The application is supposed to get information from a REST api and then populate a Table with feeds from this API https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/posts/tim_girl_2 for instance. I am getting this Error instead :

```
TypeError: posts.map is not a function
```

Now i got confused. I just need help here. It is supposed to get data from the REST api and then populate as feeds for viewing.

My code is looking like this

```
import './Home.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const MyDashBoard = () =>{
    const[posts, setPosts] = useState('');

    useEffect(() =>{
        let userId =  localStorage.getItem('userinfo');
        fetch('https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/posts/'+userId,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) =>{
            setPosts(responseJson.data);
        })
    },[]);

    return (
        <div align="center">
                <table className="headerTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                <td width="270px">
                                <p align="right"/></td>
                                <td width="108px">
                                <p align="right"/>
                                <img border="0" src="images/735145cfe0a4.png" width="103px" height="29px"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="150px">
                                <p align="center"/>
                                <input type="image" src="images/home.png" width="27" height="25" align="right" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="135">
                                    <p align="center"/>
                                    <input type="image" src="images/logout.png" width="27" height="25" align="left" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="128"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div className="uploadImagesDiv">
                    <table className="postsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="76">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <textarea rows="4" name="S1" cols="73" className="textArea" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="34">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <input type="file" name="file1" size="73" className="fileUploaderClass"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td height="34">
                               <p align="left"/>
                               <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" className="postButton" />
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div className="postsDiv">
                    {posts.map(post =>(
                        <table border="0" width="42%" height="600" className="feedsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="3">
                                <p align="left"/>&nbsp; <b>{post.username}</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="428">
                            <p align="center"/>
                            <img border="0" src={post.imgUrl} width="100%" height="100%" className="photoMain" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                               <p align="left" />&nbsp; <b>{post.posts}</b>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                    ))}
                    <p align="left"/>&nbsp;
                </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyDashBoard;
```

What do I do here to get the data from this api `https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/posts/tim_girl_2` for instance.

**Edits**

Code is Looking like this now :

```
import './Home.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const MyDashBoard = () =>{
    const[posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        let userId =  localStorage.getItem('userinfo');
        fetch('https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/posts/'+userId,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) =>{
            setPosts(responseJson);
        })
    },[]);

    return (
        <div align="center">
                <table className="headerTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                <td width="270px">
                                <p align="right"/></td>
                                <td width="108px">
                                <p align="right"/>
                                <img border="0" src="images/735145cfe0a4.png" width="103px" height="29px"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="150px">
                                <p align="center"/>
                                <input type="image" src="images/home.png" width="27" height="25" align="right" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="135">
                                    <p align="center"/>
                                    <input type="image" src="images/logout.png" width="27" height="25" align="left" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="128"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div className="uploadImagesDiv">
                    <table className="postsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="76">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <textarea rows="4" name="S1" cols="73" className="textArea" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="34">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <input type="file" name="file1" size="73" className="fileUploaderClass"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td height="34">
                               <p align="left"/>
                               <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" className="postButton" />
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div className="postsDiv">
                    {posts.map(post =>(
                        <table border="0" width="42%" height="600" className="feedsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="3">
                                <p align="left"/>&nbsp; <b>{post.username}</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="428">
                            <p align="center"/>
                            <img border="0" src={post.imgUrl} width="100%" height="100%" className="photoMain" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                               <p align="left" />&nbsp; <b>{post.posts}</b>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                    ))}
                    <p align="left"/>&nbsp;
                </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyDashBoard;
```

I still get the same Error

Comment: You have defined your state as a string, you should use an array: `const[posts, setPosts] = useState([]);`

Comment: @LucaPizzini, still gives me an Error, post.map is not a function. Please see edits

Comment: [Sample code]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be complete, yet minimal. Furthermore, edits & clarifications shouldn't simply be appended to a question but should be edited in, to make a single, seamless post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your herokuapp api, it returns this:

```
{
"error": false,
"data": [],
"message": "posts."
}
```

...so I guess you need the data from it:

```
setPosts(responseJson.data)
```

**edit**: For your better understanding: an object doesn't have a map function.

Comment: Thanks blood. Works fine now.